# Em um cenário bancário com alto volume de transações Code First pode ser superior a Database First ou vice-versa?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, .net, entity-framework, arquitetura-de-software

Estou arquitetando o desenvolvimento de uma estrutura de backend composto de microservices para uma instituição financeira. Provavelmente o maior projeto no qual já trabalhei até hoje, e estou com sérias dúvidas com relação a utilização de Code First ou Database First. Iremos utilizar o ASP.NET Core 3 com Microsoft SQL Server, tudo hospedado no Microsoft Azure. Esta é uma aplicação que devido a algumas parcerias comerciais já pode ter alguns milhões de usuários garantidos.

A praticidade do Entity Framework Core seria muito interessante, principalmente pela velocidade no processo de desenvolvimento (estamos com um timebox apertado), no entanto possuo preocupações relativas a performance com queries geradas automaticamente pela framework em um aplicativo com tantos usuários.

Em contrapartida um ORM parece ser algo interessante quando não temos todas as regras de negócio mapeadas ainda, e o banco de dados precisa acompanhar o progresso da aplicação. Imagino que as  migrations do EF Core poderiam deixar o processo muito prático, principalmente por estar pensando em trabalhar com microservices.

Existe algum material ou whitepaper referente a utilização destas técnicas para aplicações de alto volume? Particularmente estou pendendo para a utilização de code-first. Pode haver algum motivo impeditivo no cenário mencionado?

Comment: Se performance é uma preocupação ORM não deveria ser usado, né? Precisa escolher qual dos dois vai usar. O Core só tem Code First, o que pode fazer é importar o modelo do DB pra escrever o código para você, mas ainda funciona como Code First. O seu uso faz diferença, o modelo não até porque é só um modelo de desenvolvimento e não de execução. Microsserviço pode até aumentar a escala (quase sempre não precisa - você está usando um dos 30 sites mais acessados do mundo que roda monolito e pode rodar em 1 servidor) mas ele deixa tudo mais lento, e absurdamente difícil fazer certo, é show de horror

Comment: Trabalho com sistemas bancários e micro serviços... posso dizer que qualquer ORM está "banido" e a maioria segue o CQRS. Mas... depende de qual operação vai ser feita e em qual banco de dados... Aqui o conjunto de soluções incluem MongoDB, SQL Server, Redis e etc... todos eles on-premise e nas clouds...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Obrigado pelo input. Vocës trabalham com a abordagem de database first? Qual o principal motivo de terem banido os ORMS? Existe algum material, white paper ou livro que você pode me sugerir para entender melhor como as operações a nível de DB são realizadas neste segmento? Eu ainda estou optando por microservices pois pode ajudar muito no nosso time to market, mas pretendo utilizar SQL Server para armazenar todos os registros transacionais de usuários. Se quiser, estrutura como uma resposta que eu vou ter prazer em aceitar.

Comment: Basicamente o problema dos ORMS é que você não está com 100% do controle das suas queries, transações e modelagem (code-first). Não existe uma receita de bolo, apenas as boas práticas, mas cada necessidade é um caso. E no fim das contas você vai ficar restrito ao paradoxo do teorema de CAP https://medium.com/system-design-blog/cap-theorem-1455ce5fc0a0

Answer (score 0):

Ao meu ver, a vantagem de utilizar o Code First é evidentemente o ganho de produtividade. Entretanto, o problema é que essa estratégia abre brechas para desenvolvedores com pouco conhecimento em banco de dados modelar as entidades de forma que elas vão refletir em tabelas e relacionamentos pouco eficientes no banco de dados.

Por outro lado, a vantagem de utilizar o Database First é que a modelagem do banco de dados tende a ficar muito mais eficiente. Entretanto, dependendo da forma como o banco de dados é modelado, as consultas tendem a ficar mais difíceis de serem escritas no Entity Framework.

Pessoalmente falando, eu não vejo problemas em adotar o Code First, desde que você esteja trabalhando com uma equipe mais sênior, que saiba o que está sendo gerado no banco de dados e que anteveja os gargalos quando o volume de dados crescer.

É claro que o uso de SQL puro tem performance melhor que o Entity Framework, mas essa diferença costuma ser insignificante nas operações CRUD. É claro que o SQL puro tem performance muito melhor que o Entity Framework nas consultas mais complexas, mas você pode contornar esse problema modelando o banco de dados para que as consultas fiquem mais simples.

Independentemente da estratégia que você escolher, o problema é que por se tratar de uma aplicação com potencial para ter alguns milhões de usuários, talvez a grande questão deveria ser -SQL ou NoSQL?